# Error When Installing Anything

Tags: command-line, 14.10, source-code

Every time i try to install wine in the terminal i get these errors

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
wine is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  acpid:i386 dh-apparmor libc6-dev:i386 libmail-sendmail-perl
  libsys-hostname-long-perl libxv1:i386 libxvmc1:i386 linux-libc-dev:i386
  make:i386 po-debconf
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up libssl1.0.0:i386 (1.0.1f-1ubuntu9.1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libpam-gnome-keyring:amd64 (3.10.1-1ubuntu7.1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libpam-gnome-keyring:amd64 (--configure)
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libssl1.0.0:i386
 libpam-gnome-keyring:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And when i try to install it in the Ubuntu Software Center i get a error saying "requires installation of untrusted packages" and i have to keep pressing exit to get it off my screen. One time i almost got it to work on installing wine in Ubuntu SoftWare Center but in progress it kept saying "Waiting For Apt-Get To Exit. Can someone please help me with my issue? Thank you

Comment: And it says Wine is already installed when it's not i can't find it at all

Comment: You can not run apt-get on the command line at the same time you are running the software center. To find wine use `which wine`

Answer (score -1):

I think your System Might be Broken

This might Fix your Problem

First REBOOT

Then Open A **Root Terminal** and then follow these commands

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And Then Paste this To your Existing Source List **(CONTAINS FROM VIVID VELVET)**

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu utopic partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu utopic partner
```

Then Execute These Commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Maybe for New Distribution Updates

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This is for the Purpose of Re Installing Wine

```
sudo apt-get remove wine
sudo apt-get purge wine
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install wine
```